# Material 2 md-menu how to change background color for only one menu

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am using md-menu in multiple places but only in one page the menu background needs to be a different color.

When I try to do it with shadow-piercing (`/deep/` or `>>>`), it effects all the other md-menu within the application.

Here's the css that spills over:

```
>>> .mat-menu-content {
      background: skyblue;
      color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

I have this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/RpT6Bg77FrTXBs3vLciO?p=preview) to demo my problem. I added the above css for menu in Form1, but the menu in Summary page is also getting effected by it.

How can I change the background color of the md-menu only for Form1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a class to your menu

```
>>> .my-menu .mat-menu-content {
    background: skyblue;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

_

```
<md-menu #menu="mdMenu" [overlapTrigger]="false" class="my-menu">
```

Answer (score 1):

Add class to md-menu

```
<md-menu #menu="mdMenu" [overlapTrigger]="false" class="my-menu">
         <button md-menu-item>Item 1</button>
         <button md-menu-item>Item 2</button>
       </md-menu>
```

You have added class to md-button

```
<button md-raised-button color="primary" [mdMenuTriggerFor]="menu" class="my-menu">Menu</button>
```